# JBoss Forge opening Forge quick action menu

Tags: eclipse, jboss, jboss-forge

I have an issue with not getting Forge quick action menu to appear when pressing ctrl + 4 in eclipse. Instead I get a "forge command list".
I have made sure that the project is chosen in the project explorer.

When i open the forge  console i get this message
"JBoss Forge, version [ 1.4.3.Final ] - JBoss, by Red Hat, Inc. [ http://forge.jboss.org ]
[no project]"

Any idea why this is happening? 
I have been following this tutorial https://www.jboss.org/ticket-monster/introduction/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was running and older version of eclipse and the Jboss tool plugin. After updating it works as aspected.